# Typescript compiler ignores existing namespace

Tags: typescript

I would like to extend an existing JavaScript library which already exists as a global variable.

That library may principally be described as a factory function with additional properties:

```
declare function existingLib ():any
declare namespace existingLib {
// additional classes, functions, properties
}
```

I would now like to add some more stuff to this (already existing) namespace:

```
namespace existingLib {
  export const a = 'test' // just as an example
}
```

But, unfortunately, the compiler always creates a local variable `existingLib` which shadows the global one with the same name (which may easily be verified using the TypeScript Playground):

```
"use strict";
var existingLib;
(function (existingLib) {
    existingLib.a = 'test'; // just as an example
})(existingLib || (existingLib = {}));
```

How should my code look like in order to properly extend my library? Shouldn't `declare function existingLib` be sufficient tell the compiler that there already exists an "external" variable which should not be overwritten/shadowed?

Thanks in advance for any help!

**Outcome:**

With the help of Titian Cernicova-Dragomir it turned out, that TypeScript seems to assume code declaring namespaces to run in a global environment - thus, the "extra" `var` declaration may safely be inserted in order to avoid potential ReferenceErrors because of a missing global variable `existingLib`.

In my case, however, the packaging process surrounded the compiler output by an IIFE (in order to avoid pollution of the global namespace) - which made the extra `var` local and shadowed the actual global variable with the same name. The solution was to "inject" the global `existingLib` as an argument into the IIFE - now, the extra `var` statement is simply ignored and does not cause any harm any longer...

Many thanks to Titian for his ideas which finally led me to that solution!

Comment: Do you use modules? Or are these simple script files ? Also is this a library whose name you can share ?

Comment: its just a plain script file. Its content is not really relevant (in fact, any content would be sufficient to illustrate the problem). The only important detail is that this library should not be touched - just described in terms of type declarations (which I wrote myself).

Which means: perhaps, declaring a function and extending it using a namespace may have been the wrong approach?

Comment: Are you sure the include order of library and augmentation is correct ? The `existingLib || (existingLib = {})` is there to ensure that if `existingLib` is already defined it does not get overwritten. The `var` declaration should not impact an existing function declaration in any way.

Comment: `existingLib` is already present as a global variable (I just checked it). But the `var existingLib` creates a (non-initialized) local variable which shadows the global one - that's why the program fails. And (in my understanding - which might be wrong) the idea behind `declare function existingLib` is to inform the compiler about a global variable `existingLib` which should NOT be shadowed...

Comment: Local to what ? If these are script files the variable would be in the global scope. This works at runtime https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAUwB4wM6zAcwDIwBGiAFAJSIDeAvgLABQYAhgLbIYAOTEyK6WMXAWKUGiPhzgAnKIggIsiYgF5EAcijsoAITWIA9PsQArEIqYZETJGlYcANr0QM69AG5MpfTNnxEA3AzMbJzcvGg+gn4iYhLSsvJg5oiqGloAgnqGJmayFlY2qHaOLgwMiRhwjgB09nA4JBECQkRkgfQVVci19Y38vsLVTG3lCl09DU0DRNWEbUA (I added the extra var to simulate the way things would work with multuiple file, ts complains about it but it works in spite of the ts error)

Comment: It's not in global scope: I always surround my code by an IIFE in order not to pollute the global namespace - and I would prefer to keep it that way...is there any possibility to get rid of that local variable? and ask the compiler to use the global one?

Comment: How do you surround the namespace in an IIFE? This is not valid code for example `(function() {
    namespace existingLib {
 
    }
})()`

Comment: That's part of the packaging process - which worked fine until now...It seems that I have to find a way how to inject any globals into that IIFE - in that case, indeed, the extra `var existingLib` won't cause any harm. Thanks anyway for your help! Unfortunately, I can't honour your effort unless you'll write an official answer, right?

Comment: Just to let you know: after adding the library as an argument to the IIFE the extra `var` declaration in the compiled code became irrelevant and the code ran through! Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I would add an answer, just not sure I really have one, this just turned into a discussion and you found your own answer 

Comment: but you led me there! Never mind, I leave it up to you!